# saas/web-service methodologies like Twelve-Factor App?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, architecture, cloud, saas

What are some saas/web-service methodologies other than the [12-factor app](http://www.12factor.net/)?  I'm not looking for manifestos like Agile or Craftsmanship, but rather methodologies that provide specifics on how to design and architect systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Zachman Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachman_Framework)
- [TOGAF](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf8-doc/arch/)
- [Dynamic systems development method](http://www.dsdm.org/)
- [Unified Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process)
- [PRojects IN Controlled Environments 2 (PRINCE2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRINCE2)
- [Projects integrating Sustainable Methods (PRiSM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRiSM)

An overview of [Service-oriented agility: Methods for successful Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA) development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-agile1/) by IBM Architects.

An academic perspective on [Service-Oriented Design and Development Methodology](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=106517).

Comment: These are all broad frameworks for organization and process.  They don't have specific methodology around things like interfaces, logging, configuration, etc.

Comment: They are all "methodologies that provide specifics on how to design and architect systems."  SOA systems are do not require any special methological approach and actually Zachman and TOGAF do cover logging, configuration and logging (audit) extensively.  First and foremost SAAS is a business model. The fact you target architecture is SOA is immaterial at the methodology level but is tractable to agile methologies when it is new target domain for the participants, because of the opportunity too test your approach and assumptions early.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree and talk about content.  I believe that systems should be simple and that describing them shouldn't employ abstract and vague language.  The frameworks in your post use prototypical consultant-speak (I mean that in a red-flag way).  They seem on a different planet than the 12-factor app.